# Flutter mobile app backspace delete 2 characters instead of 1

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I have a page which will show a modalbottomsheet when i click on the button. In the modalbottomsheet, it has a Pinput field which i can type in values. However, when I press backspace, it deletes 2 characters instead of 1. Does anybody know what is the problem with it as the console doesnt show anything. Below is the codes for the modalbottomsheet

```
_showCouponDetails(String coupon, bool couponStatus){
    int shopPinCode;
    int pinCode;
    final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
    final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();

    return showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder:(BuildContext context) =>
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            },
            child: Container(
                width: screenWidth,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 24),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(coupon,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                )),
                        ),

                    couponStatus? Text(''):Image.asset('images/Redeemed.png', width: 100, height: 100),
                    Center(child:
                      Text('Expires on 31/12/2020')),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: screenWidth*0.8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        color: Colors.grey[200]
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text('Please ask the workshop to enter pin.'),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              PinPut(
                                fieldsCount: 5,
                                focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
                                controller: _pinPutController,
                                eachFieldHeight: 30,
                              eachFieldWidth: 30,
                              selectedFieldDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                              ),
                              followingFieldDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                              submittedFieldDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (_pinPutController){
                                  if (_pinPutController.isNotEmpty)
                                    pinCode = int.parse(_pinPutController);
                                    print (pinCode);
                                  },
                                ),
                            ]
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: screenHeight*0.05,
                              width: screenWidth *0.4,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  color: kPrimaryColor
                              ),
                              child: Center(child: Text('Redeem', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15))),
                            ),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: screenHeight*0.05,
                              width: screenWidth *0.4,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                                color: Colors.white
                              ),
                              child: Center(child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ),
      );
  }
```

Updates: Picture included. In the picture i have keyed in 1,2 and 3. Whenever i press backspace, it deletes 2 and 3 (picture 2). In picture 3, the console prints out the number twice.

[image: Picture 1]  [image: Picture 2]   [image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing my flutter channel. I was using flutter channel beta and apparently this backspace is a bug. After swittching to flutter channel stable, everything was fine.

To check your flutter channel, type the following in terminal
flutter --version

To change the flutter channel, type the following in terminal
flutter channel master

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the number adding and backspacing inside the number box? Well, that is working fine during my compilation. If not, could you add Screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Hello, yes im talking about the number inside the number box. I have added 2 pictures of the problem.

Comment: Hi Roy, the app is running perfectly fine during my compilation. If the problem is still persisting. Kindly check if:-  1.Updated to the **latest version of pinput** library(i used the latest one) or any library. 2. Try running app on a physical device (This might work)

Comment: thanks. I've tried loading on a device but its still the same. I've also upgraded to the latest library but still encounter the same problem.

Comment: In my code. If I hold the backspace button still it's deleting only one character. I want to make it like when we hold backspace key all characters start deleting, But I am only able to delete one character.  how can I achieve that?